# How can I view a table's attributes on Oracle 11g?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, database-administration

I only want to see the attributes associated with a particular table, not tuples or anything else. For an example if I have a table called `Users` and its attributes are `fName`, `lName`, and `idNumber`, I want to be able to see that these attributes are part of the `Users` table by only knowing that the table's name is `Users`.

Comment: It's not clear what kind of attributes you are looking for. Can you provide a little bit more information?

Comment: If I have a table called Users and its attributes are fName, lName, and idNumber, I want to be able to see that these attributes are part of the Users table by only knowing that the table's name is Users.

Answer (score 2):

To get the list of columns' names of a table, the `[dba][all][user]_tab_columns` data dictionary view(depending on the privileges granted to you) can be queried:

```
/* test table*/
create table users(
  fName    varchar2(11), 
  lName    varchar2(11), 
  idNumber number
)

select column_name
  from user_tab_columns  
 where table_name = 'USERS'
```

Result:

```
COLUMN_NAME
-----------
IDNUMBER    
LNAME       
FNAME
```